# Partition Generating Function and Euler Transform

Tags: generating-functions, transformation, integer-partitions

Various sources on the web give the result that if {a<sub>i</sub>} and {b<sub>i</sub>} satisfy  $$1+\sum_{n\geq 1}^n b_n z^n = \prod_{i\geq1}\frac{1}{(1-z^i)^{a_i}}$$ then we have that
$$1+B(z)=exp\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{A(z^k)}{k}$$

Setting all a<sub>i</sub>=0 then gives the generating function for the number of partitions of n, so we see that b<sub>n</sub>=p(n).

However

$$1+B(z) = \prod_{i\geq1}\frac{1}{(1-z^i)} \neq exp\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k(1-z^k)} = exp(\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{A(z^k)}{k})$$

While this equality fails, the true identity is the similar looking

$$ \prod_{i\geq1}(1-z^{-i}) = exp \sum_{k\geq1 }\frac{1}{k(1-z^k)} $$

Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: I think you mean $a_i=1$